# HttpContext via Ninject gives me a weird production only error c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ninject

I have injected the HttpContextBase via Ninject like this:

```
Kernel.Bind<HttpContextBase>()
      .ToMethod(ctx => HttpContext.Current == null ? (HttpContextBase)new NullHttpContext() : new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current))
      .InScope(HybridScope);
```

My HybridScope is like this:

```
private static object HybridScope(IContext ctx)
{
  return (object)HttpContext.Current ?? ctx;
}
```

And the empty NullHttpContext class is like this:

```
public class NullHttpContext : HttpContextBase
{

}
```

I have a CDN service with this line:

```
if (_httpContext.GetType().Name == "NullHttpContext" || (_httpContext.GetType().Name != "NullHttpContext" && _httpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection) || !Enabled) return url;
```

Which throws me this error on `_httpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection`:

> Exception: System.ArgumentException Message: Value does not fall
>   within the expected range. Source: mscorlib    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)    at
>   System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetServerVariableInternal(String
>   name)    at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.IsSecure()    at
>   -\CDNService.GetUrl(String url,
>   Boolean cache) in -\ICDNService.cs:line 59

I have been trying to figger this out, and i am unable to find any solution for this, even on google.

Is there anyone out there, who have a fix for this, or can explain why this is happening?

If i am using HttpContext.Current directly, it gives me no error.
But if i do that, it causes a huge memory leak during Ninject not being able to release the instance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just a comment: how about simplifying the `if`check to `if (_httpContext is NullHttpContext || _httpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection || !Enabled) return url`. Why? a) more refactor-safe, b) the second `||` constraint is only ever evaluated if the first doesn't evaluate to `true` - meaning you don't need to check twice whether it's a `NullHttpContext`.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit thank you for your comment, i actually made these changes myself a few minutes after posting my question, thanks though :-) the "is" keyword is pretty clever.